# Is Singular homology the "largest" possible homology theory?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

The title, as you may know already exists somewhere in this wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology but without question mark. My question has to do with the proof of the above. I have no idea unfortunately how such a statement can be proved through category theory or if needs a kind of a more intuitive/geometrical approach.

Moreover is that true for singular cohomology as well?

References with a proof or conversation of the above statements are really welcome!

Comment: Singular homology can be defined for any topological space, and due to the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms, it will agree with any other homology theory on any subcategory of $\mathrm{Top}$.

Comment: These notes might be helpful: http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2015/REUPapers/Starkey.pdf

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip thank you for your response! do you know about cohomology theory if it is still true?

Comment: Yes, there are also Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for cohomology, which also uniquely determine a cohomology theory.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: On any? I believe the result is for CW complexes.

Comment: @ThomasRot: hmm, chasing down the reference I gave does only apply to CW complexes, but it certainly is more general than that.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: I think the counterexamples can be found for spaces which are not homotopy equivalent to locally nice spaces, such as CW complexes. I think various homology theories might give different groups for something like the Milnor-Barrat example of a higher dimensional analogue of the hawaiian earring. I also remember that the stratifold homology does not agree with singular homology for "an infinite genus toruslike-stratifold". The last example is in M. Kreck's book.

Comment: I believe Cech cohomology and Singular cohomology gives a counter example.

Comment: Somebody needs to edit Wikipedia!

Comment: @ThomasRot Thomas in this wiki-page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology#Axioms_and_generalized_cohomology_theories implies in the section axioms and generalized cohomology theories that for CW complexes works fine, but apparently there are counterexamples. If you are interested and would check that and find out for which class (or discrete counterexample) fails the above please do let me know.

Comment: Cech cohomology of the topologist's sine curve (Warsaw circle) differs from its singular cohomology. Unfortunately Cech *homology* does not satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms so does not serve as a counterexample here.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris: I was just in the process of writing an answer for your question regarding complexity theory, when you deleted it. No big deal, it wasn't going to be some amazing answer, but I found your question legitimate. Anyway, given that you were attending a number theory presentation, I believe that the speaker had [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) in mind, but do keep in mind that there is also the study of the [dynamics of complex sytems](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dynamics+of+Complex+System) which to me is a highly dubious field.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris: In particular, you've got this: http://necsi.edu/publications/dcs/ - but it's far from being the only one, it was just the first result that my search got.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you a lot for that! I do really appreciate it, I deleted that seems that created more questions than answers :)! And I didn't want that! Thank you again!